# Why doesn't this function load after a successful ajax call in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [the tutorial here](http://papermashup.com/parse-xml-with-jquery/), that used to work last month, but now it isn't. I've copied the relevant code below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://papermashup.com/demos/jquery-xml/books.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
    alert("123");
});

function xmlParser(xml) {
    alert("456");

    $('#load').fadeOut();

    $(xml).find("Book").each(function () {

        $(".main").append('<div class="book"><div class="title">' + $(this).find("Title").text() + '</div><div class="description">' + $(this).find("Description").text() + '</div><div class="date">Published ' + $(this).find("Date").text() + '</div></div>');
        $(".book").fadeIn(1000);

    });

}
```

The problem is that the xmlParser() function isn't being called after the successful ajax request. It shows a 123 alert but not a 456 alert. Am I doing something wrong, or is the tutorial wrong?

I've included a relevant jsfiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/desbest/nwt3unxu/

Comment: Fixed. The jsfiddle doesn't have that.

Comment: If it is not typo as Royi said than, It seems you facing cross domain request issue. Are you keeping your xml file on same domain?

Comment: Yes I'm keeping the file on the same domain and I still get the thing not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why doesn't this function load after a successful ajax call in jquery?

It does.

From the JavaScript error console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://papermashup.com/demos/jquery-xml/books.xml`. No '`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://fiddle.jshell.net`' is therefore not allowed access.

Your request **isn't successful** (at least in Ajax terms, it is in strictly HTTP terms, but the site you are requesting the data from isn't giving the browser permission to give the data to the JavaScript from JSFiddle).

Comment: But I don't get a CORS error when I'm calling an xml file locally, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @desbest — I just copied the JSFiddle (changing the URL to books.xml) and books.xml to local files, ran a local HTTP server, and tested it. It works fine.

Comment: If it's the same domain, use the relative path in the GET request.

Comment: @HenriS. absolute or relative both work, there is no reason to recommend relative ...and in many projects where you have the same code running across multiple nested directories relative will fail

Comment: For some reason it's not working when I run the code on my computer. https://gist.github.com/desbest/8541b7d27b044bb6d395 but I get a successful ajax call http://i.imgur.com/IM9CBJW.png Also the error console is blank.

Comment: @charlietfl Of course, but for efficiency, maintenance and movability it's recommand to use relative links.

Comment: See my comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31562011/why-doesnt-this-function-load-after-a-successful-ajax-call-in-jquery-updated

Comment: @HenriS. can have absolute that doesn't contain protocol, domain , port etc... a leading `/` is absolute

Comment: @charlietfl I know, but I mean relative or internal absolute links: without domain included. ;-)

Comment: I've fixed the problem now. Thank you all for your help.