# Why doesn't this function load after a successful ajax call in jquery? (updated)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using [the tutorial here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkWja.png), that used to work last month, but now it isn't. I've copied the relevant code below.

```
<script>
        (function($) { //In case jQuery no conflict is being used
            $(document).ready(function() { //wait for document ready
                $("#loaddaold").click(function () {
                    alert("123");
                    //$( "#duplicateshere" ).empty();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "ajax-oldmessages.php",
                        dataType: "xml",
                        success: xmlParser
                    });
                });
            });
            function xmlParser(xml) {
                alert("456");
                //$("#rev2").slideDown();
                $(xml).find("result").each(function () {
                $("#appendhere").append('<a href="/debates/' + $(this).find("id").text() + '">' + $(this).find("title").text() + '</a><br>');
                //$(".book").fadeIn(1000);
                });
            }
        })(jQuery);
        // http://www.webdevdoor.com/jquery/javascript-delay-input-field-change/
        // http://papermashup.com/parse-xml-with-jquery/
        // (not used) http://www.paulund.co.uk/process-each-node-of-xml-in-jquery
        </script>
```

The problem is that the xmlParser() function isn't being called after the successful ajax request. It shows a 123 alert but not a 456 alert. Am I doing something wrong, or is the tutorial wrong?

[image: ajax okay http 200]

Previously on the other question I was told it was a CORS issue, but I was calling the file off my computer, and in my example, so what is the problem now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't this function load after a successful ajax call in jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561644/why-doesnt-this-function-load-after-a-successful-ajax-call-in-jquery)

Comment: jQuery supports an `error` handler as well as a `success` handler. Look at the three arguments you get in it. Look at your JS console.

Comment: Any error in the console ?

Comment: The error console doesn't say anything. It's blank.

Comment: did you try the `error` handler as @Quentin suggested?

Comment: Using this error handler `error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                alert(xhr.status);
                                alert(thrownError);
                            }` it says I'm using invalid xml, so I used an xml validator, fixed the error, and now it works. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if youre using

```
dataType: "xml"
```

and if you have an invalid xml in youre response then success wont triger

check youre response because its invalid... if you want to test your code just change

```
dataType: "html"
```

and you will see your alert(456) that confirms invalid xml data

I've duplicated your issue and by placing in my response a valid xml, code was running fine

Also if youre expected data is just an string that contains an id, try using

```
dataType: "xml text"
```

NOTE: As of jQuery 1.5, jQuery can convert a dataType from what it received in the Content-Type header to what you require